# Convert String to desired format / Remove periods in the middle of sentence

Tags: regex, notepad++

Have this text sequence, how do we get it to look like desired output.

```
AAAAAAA ................................................ 28.02%
AAAAA-BBBBB, AB ........................................ 16.50%
AAAAAAA ................................................ 28.02%
AAAAA-BCCCC, AB ........................................ 16.50%
CCCCCCC ................................................ 28.02%
AAAAA-DDDDD, AB ........................................ 16.50%
FFFFFFF ................................................ 28.02%
AAAAA-BBBBB, AB ........................................ 16.50%
```

Trying to get into a format like this --

```
AAAAAAA | 28.02%
AAAAA-BBBBB, AB | 16.50%
AAAAAAA | 28.02%
AAAAA-BBBBB, AB |16.50%
AAAAAAA | 28.02%
AAAAA-BBBBB, AB | 16.50%
```

Using Pipe delimiter, that way I can load it into DB (since I can't use commas,they're in the first part of the string).

so far I've tried this - without much success, any help would be appreciated. Using Notepad++ for processing the regex.

```
\.(?!$)
replace with blank
```

Comment: Find: \B\.+    replace all with `pipe `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply match the dots(**minimum 2** otherwise dot inside float value will also match which is not required here) and replace with the pipe `|` character,

Match : `\.{2,}`

Replace: `|`

**REGEX DEMO:** https://regex101.com/r/HxVFbl/1

Comment: Works like a charm :) Appreciate it.

Comment: @CustomerHell glad it helps you somehow :)

Answer (score 1):

Try Finding: `([^.]+) \.+ (.+)`

and replacing with: `$1 | $2`

**Explanation**

Find: `([^.]+) \.+ (.+)`

- `([^.]+)` - all that is not a dot '`.`' in a capture group (#1)
- `\.+` - space, one or more dots `...`, space
- `(.+)` - simply the rest of the string in another capture group (#2)

Replace: `$1 | $2`

- `$1` - contents of capture group #1
- `|` - space, pipe, space
- `$2` - contents of capture group #2

Comment: I'm not a fan of using `\.+` to match the series of dots, because a decimal number also has a single dot in it.  See the Sunny answer for an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Don't be panic, it could be done super easily, just forget above all complex answers.  just select dots one or more with white space, and there you go.

```
(\.+ )
```

Then replace with pipe and white space(| ) character

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/yoxb9U/3

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below regex

Match: `[.]+`

Replace: `|`